# Get file base on pattern and only the latest

Tags: php

I have a task ini PHP to get the latest file in a directory based on a pattern. So the file in directory looks like:

> /cpca/mp_bi_rate_20140616.xml
>
> /cpca/mp_bi_rate_20140613.xml
>
> /cpca/mp_bi_rate_20140609.xml
>
> /cpca/mp_bi_rate_20140602.xml
>
> /cpca/mp_bi_ihks_20140616.xml
>
> /cpca/mp_bi_ihks_20140615.xml
>
> /cpca/mp_bi_ihks_20140614.xml
>
> /cpca/ca_puexp_20140611.xml
>
> /cpca/ca_puexp_20140610.xml
>
> /cpca/ca_puexp_20140609.xml

so in this scenario, i need to pick the file mp_bi_rate_20140616.xml, mp_bi_ihks_20140616.xml, and ca_puexp_20140611.xml

perhaps i need a combination between glob anda regex, but i kinda lost here...
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have files with such pattern, it's quite possible that you only need to get file that was modified as the last one (probably files won't be modified after new one has been created).

So what you can do is:

```
<?php

  $files = glob('/cpca/mp_bi_rate_*.xml');

  array_multisort(array_map('filemtime', $files), SORT_NUMERIC, SORT_DESC, $files);

  echo $files[0]; // file that was modified as the last one
```

Of course, because you have 3 patterns and you need 3 files, you need to do it for each pattern.

Answer (score 0):

**Naive approach.** You could get all relevant file names into an array with `opendir()` and then `sort()` these values. You could then go through each value with `foreach()` and take the first one with a given prefix, i.e. the first file to start with "mp_bi_rate_" is the one you want, etc.

This is not really scalable, though, since you would have to sort a huge array full of irrelevant names and then loop through tons of irrelevant values to get three file names you want.

---

**A cooler approach.** Let's do this step by step – first, we need a way to get the date and the file prefix. The date is always something like "20140614", yes? It's always the same length? Then we can get to the date with the following code (given an example value in `$file`).

```
$file = '/cpca/mp_bi_rate_20140609.xml';
$date = substr($file, -12, 8);
// Get everything before "20140609.xml"
$prefix = substr($file, 0, -12);
```

Using `substr()` over a regular expression should make us faster, hopefully. All you need from there is to keep a max value for each file, i.e. something like:

```
$max_date = array();
$max_file = array(); // array to keep the full file name
foreach($files as $file) {
   $date = substr($file, -12, 8);
   $prefix = substr($file, 0, -12);
   if(!isset($max_date[$prefix]) || $date > $max_date[$prefix]) {
       $max_date[$prefix] = $date;
       $max_file[$prefix] = $file;
   }
}
```

`$max_file` will then hold the oldest file by prefix (e.g. `$max_file['mp_bi_rate_']`)

If you want things fancy, you can use `-13` in the subtsring for `$prefix` so you don't have that ending underscore.